# 'Illegal access' error when trying to concatenate string

Tags: node.js

For some reason, I'm getting a strange error when trying to append a character to a string. The script is hosted on app engine, which could be causing the problem. Here's a snippet of my code

```
var temp = '';
for (var i = 0; i = array.length; i++){
  var current = array[i];
  if (temp.length == 20){
    //do stuff
    temp = '';
  } 
  else{
    temp += current;
  }
}
```

Now, this is some pretty simple code that I feel should be working. But when this loop is triggered in my app, I get the following error.

```
2018-07-18 17:52:06 default[version]  /app/app.js:101
2018-07-18 17:52:06 default[version]        else temp += current;
2018-07-18 17:52:06 default[version]                     ^
2018-07-18 17:52:06 default[version]  illegal access
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error. Searching around hasn't returned many results as to what illegal access is let alone what could be causing this in my example.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the illegal access, but this isn't going to work: `i = array.length`. The loop will run forever.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yep, that was the problem. Changed = to < and everything worked just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this `i = array.length` inside your `for-loop`, and then reading from `array[i]` is basically an out of index. This could be the problem.

Comment: That worked, can't believe that I spent that long trying to wrap my head around a simple typo. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking this answer as the accepted one if it solved your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When testing this I kept getting an error until I changed

from

```
var temp = '';
```

to

```
String temp = '';
```